# List installed packages with the repo they came from?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

With rpm it is possible to list installed packages with additional info

```
rpm -qa --queryformat "%-35{NAME} %-35{DISTRIBUTION} %{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\n" | sort -k 1,2 -t " " -i
```

which will produce something like

```
xorg-x11-drv-ur98                   (none)                              1.1.0-1.1
xorg-x11-drv-vesa                   CentOS-5                            1.3.0-8.3.el5
xorg-x11-drv-vga                    (none)                              4.1.0-2.1
xorg-x11-drv-via                    (none)                              0.2.1-9
```

On Ubnutu server would I like to list all installed packages and show from which repository in came from.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at "man dpkg-query".  The following should get you started:

```
    skx@precious:~$ dpkg-query --showformat="\${Package}\t\${Version}\t\${Origin}\n" --show \*
```